# Find item in Perl constant array

Tags: arrays, perl, constants

Hi Stack overfloweans,

I am finding a value in an array which is a constant allowed_value. If the main_value equals any of the values in allowed_value array, then I am printing the message 'Allowed value is correct'. So I have done the following piece of code.

```
use constant allowed_value => qw(value1 value2);

my $main_value = 'value2';

my @attr = (allowed_value);

print "Allowed value is correct" if grep $_ eq $main_value, @attr;
```

Is there any way to make the code better and simplify the code ? 
Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: You could also put the allowed values in a hash, then you would avoid the `grep` call (which can be slower than a hash lookup). For example: `print "Allowed value is correct\n" if $attr{$main_value}`

Comment: Can also use `List::Util::any` -- `say "good" if any { $_ eq $main_value } (allowed_value);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` is fine for small sets, but it has to search the whole set every time.

For larger sets you can do this a bit faster using [List::Util's any() function](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#any). This has the advantage over `grep` that it will stop searching when it matches once. Assuming random data, on average you'll search half the list.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;
use List::Util 'any';

use constant allowed_values => qw(value1 value2);
my $main_value = 'value3';

say "Good" if any { $_ eq $main_value } allowed_values;
```

However, that still searching through even part of `allowed_values` every time. This is inconsequential for small sets of allowed values, but when it gets large it can get slow.

Instead [use a hash as a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)#Implementations). It's a bit more work to set up, but it's more convenient and will perform the same no matter how large the set.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use constant allowed_values => {
    value1 => 1,  # any true value will do
    value2 => 1,
};
my $main_value = 'value2';

say "Good" if allowed_values->{$main_value};
```

And if your list of allowed values is long, you can generate the hash from a list avoiding a bunch of typing.

```
use constant allowed_values => {
    map { $_ => 1 }
    qw(value1 value2)
};
```

---

The downside is "constant" references aren't really constant. Only the reference is constant, the contents of that reference can be changed.

```
allowed_values->{foo} = 42;  # this is "fine"
```

If that's a concern, use [Const::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/Const::Fast) instead.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use Const::Fast qw(const);
const my %allowed_values => (
    map { $_ => 1 }
    qw(value1 value2)
);
my $main_value = 'value2';

say "Good" if $allowed_values{$main_value};
```

Unless you *really* need an inlined constant, and generally you don't.

Comment: Might be nice to include a benchmark showing the two versions of linear growth (grep vs any) using an "average case" data set.

Comment: @Daxim Thank you for the info about Const::Fast, I'll recommend it over Readonly in the future; it's certainly less awkward. However, materially changing other's answers in an edit is inappropriate. In the future, leave a comment or write a supplemental answer.

Comment: @DavidO It did occur to me that `any` might have a constant cost higher than `grep` such that `grep` wins at smaller arrays (though both are written in C, so probably not). And the benchmark would be interesting (well volunteered). Practically, skip all that and use a hash.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how large your file is, i would use if (exists) and map the array into a hash. Once wrote a programm with a lot of greps, took ours to run through 400k lines, when i replaced most of the greps, came down to under 20 seconds.